# Why are my multiple containers of a Neo4j image sharing data with Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, neo4j

I am trying to set up Docker and Neo4j. I want to create 3 seperate databases on 3 different ports.

To get the image:
`sudo docker pull neo4j`

And then I create 3 containers like this:

`sudo docker run -d --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-01/data:/data --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-01/logs:/logs neo4j:latest`

`sudo docker run -d --publish=7475:7474 --publish=7688:7687 --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-02/data:/data --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-02/logs:/logs neo4j:latest`

`sudo docker run -d --publish=7476:7474 --publish=7689:7687 --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-03/data:/data --volume=$HOME/db-neo-test-03/logs:/logs neo4j:latest`

Then I connect to `<ipaddress>:7474` to set up the initial password.

Now when I connect to the other port `7475`, I suddenly have set up a password, and if I add a node here, I can retrieve this node in all the other containers.

How do I set this up so the data is isolated, and I can use different passwords for each database instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I connect to `<ipaddress>:7474` to set up the initial password. Now when I connect to the other port `7475`, I suddenly have set up a password, and if I add a node here, I can retrieve this node in all the other containers.

You are seeing this behavior because the [Neo4j Browser](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) connects to `bolt://<ipaddress>:7687` by default.

So even though you are accessing the Neo4j Browser at `<ipaddress>:7475`, it's connecting to `bolt://<ipaddress>:7687`, and you are still seeing the data from the first container.

> How do I set this up so the data is isolated, and I can use different passwords for each database instance?

- Navigate to `<ipaddress>:7475` in a web browser.
- Open the "Browser Settings" panel by clicking on the gear icon in the sidebar.
- Enter `bolt://<ipaddress>:7688` in the "URI" field under the "Network Connection" section.
- Reload the page and verify that you can now set a different password and that you are no longer seeing the data from the first container.

Comment: With the last 2 versions of neo4j (3.2.x and 3.3.x) this seems no longer possible through the UI. After a disconnect you can connect to your preferred endpoint though, so just run  :server disconnect